# How to assign "fixed work" task to multiple resources taking vacations into account

Tags: ms-project

Let's say you have a small project. The team has estimated all the tasks as 300 days of effort.
I have 5 developers in the team, and I want MS Project to tell me when the project will complete considering vacations and working schedule of my team member.
In order to do that:
I'm creating a Task "Development" with fixed work "300d", and task type "Fixed Work".
Then I create 5 resources, and specify a 2 week vacation for one of the developers somewhere in the middle of the schedule.
Then I assign my 5 development resources to this task.

The problem is, the 300d distributed evenly to all 5 development resources. And If one of them have a two weeks vacation in between, due to that particular resource the work will be finished 2 weeks later, where other 4 resources are sitting and doing nothing for 2 weeks. Total duration is 70 days.

[what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf2tn.png)

What I want to get is: work is distributed accordingly through all 5 resources unevenly in a way that the whole task finishes as earlier as possible taking most of the usable time from all developers.

That's how I would expect it to work. In that particular case I was distributing hours manually.

[what i would expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvsYZ.png)

Is there a possibility in MS Project to do something like this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: As this question is not about programming, but rather how to use the application, it belongs either on the superuser site or even better, post to the [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues with how you are approaching the problem.

**1. Rather than just planning out the manpower hours estimated to be needed for the entire project on a single line item, You should plan out the tasks that will need to be done to accomplish "Small Project"**

If you discretely plan out the tasks that need to be accomplished to satisfy the scope of "Small project", you can establish dependency (predecessor/successor) relationships between your tasks and figure out what tasks need to be done before you can move on to others. When you do this it will give you a good idea of how long the total duration of the project will take and likely be more accurate than just relying on an estimate based on the manpower hours estimate your developers give you. Find out what tasks they actually need to do, not just how many hours they think the whole project will take them. This will also allow you to plan out the utilization of your resources better because you'll be able to assign specific resources to specific tasks, and not all of your resources need to be on every task.

**2. In general I would avoid using the *Task Usage* form.**

I noticed you are altering resources in the task usage form, but unless you are *really* experienced with Microsoft Project I would avoid ever touching that, as it's really easy to set the period of performance of resources assigned to a task to be different than the actual period of performance of the task itself. This will cause MS Project to behave unusually, and it can be hard for an unexperienced user to understand why. This usually leads to pain and frustration. This leads me to my next bit of advice:

**3. If you really want to specify a resource's vacation time, it's better to adjust the calendar associated the resource to exclude those dates as working dates.**

In your situation with only 5 resources on your project, this can be fairly easy to do. You can accomplish this 2 different ways (I'll start with the easiest option):

**1. You can add resource specific exclusion dates to the default calendar in your project**

You can accomplish this by opening the Resource Sheet table and then clicking the **Project** tab then **Change Working Times**. If you have the Resource Sheet open instead of the Gantt chart, you can specify the resource that is going to be effected by the exceptions:

[image: resource specific calendar exceptions]

In this example you can see that I would be excluding (removing) 8/23/21 thru 9/3/21  as working days for the SW Engineer resource, without needing to change the calendar used by the resource completely.

**2. You can completely change the calendar used by particular resources to be different than the default calendar set for the project.**

You can accomplish this by going into the **Resource Sheet** and opening the **Base Calendar** column:

[image: Base Calendar]

From here you can assign any calendar that exists in the project to the resource. Of course this means you would need to create the calendars and assign exclusion dates to them.

To create a calendar, click the **Project** tab then click **Change Working Times**. Click **Create New Calendar** on the form that opens up and give it a name:

[image]

From there you can add exclusion dates and all that.

**Note**: In a larger project with many resources, I would recommend ***not*** messing with the calendar for the resources at all. It just gets hard to deal with when there are a lot of resources.